# SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512") throws NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, algorithm, security, sha

After a little bit of research and some work I finally was able to hash salt the password now there is a question which is on my mind I have used the SHA1 method and I would like to try to use the SHA512 because I was told it's better (more secure) so the following is my code its a little bit all over the place but I think its comprehensible so:

```
public class Safety
{
   //calling some parameters for possible later changes
   public static final String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
   public static final int saltbytesize = 24;
   public static final int hashbytesize = 24;
   public static final int iterations = 1000;
   public static final int iIndex = 0;
   public static final int sIndex = 1;
   public static final int pbkIndex = 2;

   public static Users passwordHash(Users user) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                                       InvalidKeySpecException
   {
      SecureRandom sR = new SecureRandom();

      byte[] pws = new byte[saltbytesize];

      sR.nextBytes(pws);
      byte[] pwh = pbkdf2(user.getPassword().toCharArray(), pws, iterations, hashbytesize);

      user.setPassword(toHex(pwh));

      byte[] sas = new byte[saltbytesize];

      sR.nextBytes(sas);

      byte[] sah = pbkdf2(user.getsA().toCharArray(), sas, iterations, hashbytesize);

      user.setsA(toHex(sah));

      user.setUserhash(pws);

      user.setSahash(sas);

      return user;
   }

   public static boolean hashpassword(String username, String password, Users user)
   throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
          InvalidKeySpecException
   {
      byte[] pws = user.getUserhash();

      byte[] pwh = pbkdf2(password.toCharArray(), pws, iterations, hashbytesize);

      String searcher = toHex(pwh) + username;

      String searched = user.getPassword() + user.getUsername();

      if (searcher.equals(searched))
      {
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   private static byte[] pbkdf2(char[] password, byte[] salt,
                                int iterations, int bytes)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
   {
      PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
      SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
      return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
   }

   private static String toHex(byte[] array)
   {
      BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);

      String hex = bi.toString(16);

      int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();

      if (paddingLength > 0)
         return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
      else
         return hex;
   }
}
```

So that's my code, however, I have not been able to make that SHA512 and I have already tried `public static final String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512"` but that doesn't seem to be the right string for the algorithm since it throws the no such algorithm exception.

I also welcome any changes that would make the code better.

as stated above!
relevant few line(s) of code

> > > > > public static final String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512"<<<<<

Comment: always format your code to look pretty if you're asking people to look at it. Clarity of code is half the question.

Comment: Thank you and I know that but the way I hack kind off limits my ability to make it look pretty.

Comment: not really. the code you pasted has misaligned spacing and condensed statements, etc. at the very least fix that to be nice to potential question-answerers =)

Comment: Fixed it. The main problem with your code formatting appears to have been tabs - there should **never** be tabs in code, and the editing display and the output may use different tab stops, so the indentation may look different. Also, if you use a decent IDE (say NetBeans), it's actually rather difficult to write code without it having decent formatting.

Comment: TY @Dukeling you are my hero :)

Comment: Can you trim down your example to just a few relevant lines of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible out of the box

The OpenJDK implementation does only provide a [PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory.java) which has the "HmacSHA1" digest harcoded. As far as I tested, the Oracle JDK is not different in that sense.

What you have to do is derive the `PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory` (come on, it is **open**!) and add a parameter to its constructor. You may avoid the mess of creating your own `Provider`, and just initialize and use your factory as follows:

```
PBKDF_SecretKeyFactory kf = new PBKDF_SecretKeyFactory("HmacSHA512");
KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password,salt,iterations,bitlen);
byte key[] = kf.engineGenerateSecret(ks).getEncoded();
```

Comment: Do i need to save the key[] i mean in a database?

Comment: Yes. Despite the name, the resulting "key" is actually the output of the PBKDF. An attacker cannot (but by brute force) derive the original password from the "key".

Comment: one more thing i should have asked before hand when someone logs in what i do is retrieve the key and salt and hash it again?more properly what is the use of the key? or is it actually the hashed password and i am too thick to understand?

Comment: The "key" is the hashed password. When someone logs in, you hash the provided password again (with the same salt, algorithm and number of iterations) and test if the hashes match. Te advantage is that the password is never stored in your database.

Comment: i tried it and it says PBKDF_SecretKeyFactory cannot be resolved as a type?

Comment: That class doesn't exists. You will have to write it. See te source for `PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory` linked above.

Comment: um i understood that but excuse my ....."knowledgementness".... how ever how do i write it exactly the link you gave me is to a class named ´PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory´ ?

Comment: I think the changes are trivial: you need a factory for PBKDF with "HmacSHA512", class `PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory` is a factory for PBKDF with "HmacSHA1": **copy the source, rename it, replace "HmacSHA1" by "HmacSHA512", and have a happy new year**.

Comment: Happy new year to you too and may your next year be what you want it to be i will try it and give you feed back hopefully it works and I start working on my next step :)

Comment: i think i also need to update my JDK because there is a class that isnt installed in that class ill try installing these classes and experiment a little

Comment: Java 8 now has PBKDF2HmacSHA512 available - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html