# NoSuchAlgorithmException with SecretKeyFactory

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

I keep getting a NoSuchAlgorithmExeception when I'm passing PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 to getInstance().

Why is this happening. Am I missing some imports?

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameters;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.*;

class AES
{
    static public String encrypt(String input, String password)
    {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte salt[] = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
        byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        String text = new String(ciphertext, "UTF-8");
        return text;
    }
}
```

Also is there a way to use SHA2 instead of SHA1 ?

Comment: Are you using Oracle JDK or OpenJDK?

Comment: May be you need to install the Java Cryptographic Extension http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using OpenJDK, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807647/secretkeyfactory-getinstancepbkdf2withhmacsha512-throws-nosuchalgorithmexcep) might be your case. The accepted answer states that:

> The OpenJDK implementation does only provide a
>   [PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory.java) which has the "HmacSHA1" digest harcoded.
>   As far as I tested, the Oracle JDK is not different in that sense.
>
> What you have to do is derive the PBKDF2HmacSHA1Factory (come on, it
>   is open!) and add a parameter to its constructor. You may avoid the
>   mess of creating your own Provider, and just initialize and use your
>   factory as follows:
>
> ```
> PBKDF_SecretKeyFactory kf = new PBKDF_SecretKeyFactory("HmacSHA512");
> KeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password,salt,iterations,bitlen);
> byte key[] = kf.engineGenerateSecret(ks).getEncoded();
> ```

About using SHA2, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840206/sha2-password-hashing-in-java) might have what you're looking for. Use this code snippet:

> ```
> public byte[] hash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
> {   
>     MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");        
>     byte[] passBytes = password.getBytes();
>     byte[] passHash = sha256.digest(passBytes);
>     return passHash;
> }
> ```